# Obtaining path that follows the domain

Tags: python, django

Within my view, I'm interested in obtaining the characters that follow the domain  name.

For example, if a user types https://www.example.com/aboutus into the address bar, I want to be able to grab only '/aboutus' and assign it to a variable.

Similarly, if they enter www.example.com/aboutus or example.com/aboutus, I want to obtain only '/aboutus' and assign it to a variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can access it with the `path` property of the request object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path

Comment: linkpath = HttpRequest().path isn't working. linkpath is null even when I go to example.com/thisismypath/. Any thoughts?

Comment: you said you're within a view, and all view functions take the request object as their first parameter. By convention, this is called `request`. So you can just use the path property on that: `request.path`

(You don't create HttpRequest objects yourself, one is automatically instantiated for you by Django when the user makes an actual request.)

Comment: Thanks Robin! I'll give this a shot!

Comment: request.path was what I needed. Thanks so much!